# Other clients do not execute RotorScript

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two players network game in the unity3d, with one of the player being helicopter. Helicopter prefab has a child component "Rotor" with RotorScript attached. When I check the game on two computers, Rotor does not rotate on the client sides. The only side on which Rotor is rotating is client side which directly control helicopter, on the other sides rotor is static (does not rotate) even if helicopter is flying on every sides. 
Any suggestions  ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to broadcast your player movement to other players and receive movement from others. if using photon networking you can send RPC containing the user id and broadcast to every player . now every player will listen to it and using the id it will determine which player to move.

in case your helicopter rotor u have manually rotate using script on each machine and stop it when you get broadcast saying this helicopter with this id stopped .

Comment: I am pretty new to unity3d. But let me describe what i have, i have control buttons forward - W , down-S, A-left, D-right. Shift( when i push the shift button rotar is starting to rotate and helicopter is moving slowly verticaly) on client mashine rotar is rotating but only here , on the othe mashines rotar is static , but helicopter is moving verticlly there too, also W,S,A,D buttons works everywhere(on every mashins) so problem is just in this rotor rotation on others not clint mashines.

Comment: Regarding to netwok i strikly followed (Multiplayer and Networking - from unity3d documentation) HelicopterPrefab- add NetworkIdentity componnet , then add NetworkTransform componnet and so on. Also i have NetwokManager object which acctually control the network part of the game , having NetworkManager componnet and NetworkManager HUD componnet. Is that photon networking ?

Comment: no thats unity's own networking . so you have network transform component added to helicopter . try adding it to rotor too.

Comment: I tried this already. Helicopter has already NetworkIdentity component + NetworkTransform component.Rotar is a child of helicopter and if i add to Rotar NetworkTransform component as you advised me it comes together with NetworkIdentity by default , i can not have Network Transform without Network Indentity, but now is a problem Helicopter prefab would have two Networkidentity (one own and from the rotar) and unity3d shows me error :

Comment: " The prefab 'HelicopterModel' has multiple NetworkIdentity components. There can only be one NetworkIdentity on a prefab, and it must be on the root object.
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkManagerHUD:OnGUI()"

Comment: apprently there is new system for childs in unity 5.2 . http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkTransformChild.html     you can add Network transform child to rotor n the root of rotor means helicopter should have network transform added to it

Comment: I did what you said.I have child object which is rotated ( Helicopter rotar) I add NetworkTransformChild to the root(helicopter object) and droped the child object (rotar) in target field and still rotar does not rotate on othes clients, only on local mashine rotar is ok(rotate).